# how to combine two arrays values into one?

Tags: php, laravel

i trying to get booking seat when schedules_id equal to request schedules_id then show all seat which belongs to schedules_id but getting more separated  array's

Insert

```
$booking               = new Bookings();
$booking->users_id     = 4;
$booking->schedules_id = $schedules_id;
$booking->buses_id     = $buses_id;
$booking->routes_id    = $routes_id;
$booking->seat         = implode(',', $seat);
$booking->price        = $request->price;
$booking->profile      = 'pending';
```

Collect

```
class PassengersController extends Controller
{
    public function booking(Request $request)
    {
        //river is used to pass important params with flow of it from page to page
        $seat         = $request->seat;
        $buses_id     = $request->buses_id;
        $schedules_id = $request->schedules_id;
        $data         = Buses::where('buses_id', $buses_id)->first();
        $seat         = json_decode($data->seat_layout, true);
        $front        = json_decode($data->front_layout, true);
        $bookingSeat  = Bookings::whereColumn('schedules_id', 'schedules_id')->get();

        $bookingSeat = $bookingSeat->map(function ($bookSeat) {
            $bookSeat->seat = explode(",", $bookSeat->seat);
            return $bookSeat;
        });

        return view('frontend.booking', ['seat' => $seat, 'buses_id' => $buses_id, 'schedules_id' => $schedules_id, 'front' => $front, 'bookingSeet' => $bookingSeat]);

    }
}
```

table

```
bookings_id users_id schedules_id buses_id routes_id seat price profile
    1           1         6           1       3        1  Null  pending
    2           1         6           1       3        2  Null  pending
```

my array look like this:

```
#items: array:2 [▼

    0 => Bookings {#431 ▶}
        "bookings_id" => 1
        "users_id" => 1
        "schedules_id" => 6
        "buses_id" => 1
        "routes_id" => 3
        "seat" => "1"
        "price" => null
        "profile" => "pending"
        "created_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
    1 => Bookings {#432 ▶}
        "bookings_id" => 2
        "users_id" => 1
        "schedules_id" => 6
        "buses_id" => 1
        "routes_id" => 3
        "seat" => "2"
        "price" => null
        "profile" => "pending"
        "created_at" => "2019-04-10 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2019-04-10 00:00:00"
```

but what i want i don't want to duplicate same data again and again. problem is my booking.blade.php show like 2 buses seat layout. ex if one bus have 50 seat
im getting 100 seats in blade.php

my expect result looks like this :

```
#items: array:1 [▼

0 => Bookings {#431 ▶}
        "bookings_id" => 1,2
        "users_id" => 1
        "schedules_id" => 6
        "buses_id" => 1
        "routes_id" => 3
        "seat" => "1","2"
        "price" => null
        "profile" => "pending"
        "created_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
```

or any other suggestion are more helpful for me.
Thanks advance

Comment: Try this example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302 or simple `array_unique()`

Comment: Keys must be unique, if you combine them, you will lose all but the last one.... That is a fact, unless you remove the keys, then it's just mess.

Comment: @SamiAhmedSiddiqui tried but got this "array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"

Comment: They are not duplicates,  How do you plan to resolve this `"created_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"` and `"created_at" => "2019-04-10 00:00:00"`, Your just ignoring this in the "expected" results, there are a few of "these",

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yeah ur right i also thought , so do i have a any other way to pass my seat data into blade or using ~profile~ values?

Answer (score 0):

It's not two arrays that you're trying to merge but two entities, each represent one row in your bookings table, in my opinion they souldn't be merged and here's the main  reasons

- Each object represent one row in your database, if you merge them like you want to do how do you edit one ? delete one ? etc...
- The booking class is like a blueprint for one "booking", not all of them
- You don't "duplicate same data again and again", you juste got the same property name for different objects with differents values :)

There is probably 100 more reasons but they're the first one that came to me 
I hope this can help you

Comment: so do i have a any other way to pass my seat data into blade or using ~profile~ values?